# Use text from cell with IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have two Google Sheets: the first contains data per week and the second gives an overview of that data. The sheets in the first are named by week. For example: `Week 1`, `Week 2`, `Week 3`, `Week 4` ... The sheets in the second contain one cell which has the same text as the sheet names of the first document. This cell is A1.

Using the IMPORTRANGE function I want to show some data from the first (data) document in the second (overview) document. Currently the IMPORTRANGE formula looks like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/...; "Week 1!C2:C5")
```

As you can see I have to change the sheet name I reference to manually. I want it to change automatically using the text in cell A1. So it should look like this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/...; "A1!C2:C5")
```

Is it possible to do it like this or do I need a script and how can I make it work?

Comment: Are you willing to use a third-party tool? In this case I can write an answer using [Import Sheet](http://importsheet.com/install).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your tip about using ranges, I will use it in the future. You suggested the following formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/...; A1)
```

It didn't work. I got it to work with the following formula:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/..."; (A1&"!C2:C5"))
```

Comment: no no. there was a typo in the answer. use a comma instead of a semicolon. remeber that ALL arguments in formulas are ALWAYS separated by commas. (Semicolons are used with curly braces when you concatenate arrays).

Comment: There are no real arguments in the formula, just references... It worked with the second formula, I'm using it and it works just like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

sure, just try it:

```
 =IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/..., A1)
```

I also recommemnd you use named ranges (google it). this allows you to just type in "week1" into cell A1, instead of something like "Sheet3!A1:B343." Without named ranges any complex spreadsheet will turn your formulas into an indecipherable mess.